# How to add new configuration with Gradle Kotlin-dsl

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

with gradle-groovy it is possible to create a new configuration with:

```
configurations {
    explode
}

dependencies {
    explode (group: 'org.apache.samza', name: 'samza-shell', ext: 'tgz', classifier: 'dist', version: "$SAMZA_VERSION")
}
```

But I don't know how to do that with the kotlin-dsl. I tried:

```kotlin
val explode by configurations
    
dependencies {
    explode(group = "org.apache.samza", name = "samza-shell",  ext = "tgz", classifier = "dist", version = samzaVersion)
    // "explode"(group = "org.apache.samza", name = "samza-shell",  ext = "tgz", classifier = "dist", version = samzaVersion)
}
```

but without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Could you please try:

```kotlin
val explode by configurations.creating
```

or:

```kotlin
val explode = configurations.create("explode")
```

The following `build.gradle.kts` script works fine:

```kotlin
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val explode by configurations.creating

dependencies {
    explode("org.apache.samza:samza-shell:0.13.1")
}
```